# How can I apply the exact argument of the Match function in R to one variable when I am also using the propensity score

Tags: r, match, matching, exact-match

I want to estimate the Average Treatment Effect on the Treated (ATT) using the *Match* function of {Matching} in R, with a propensity score as the distance and one-to-one matching as the matching method. In the same matching model, I want to use the *exact* argument and apply it to one specific variable.

After having ran a logit function to estimate the propensity score as following:

```
glm1 <- glm(treat~AREA_HA + SUMVIV_TOT + SUMPOB + COUNT + luz + potable + cocina_ele + altitudeme + river_mean + 
          paved_mean + unpaved_me + VDep_mean + VNacional_ + VVecinal_m + temp_mean + rain_mean + dccpp_mean + 
          distfloss_ + idh_mean + bmass_mean + slope_mean + distANP_me + ker10_mean + titled + for10 + for10_per + 
          floss_yr001 + floss_yr002 + floss_yr003 + floss_yr004 + floss_yr005 + floss_yr006 + floss_yr007 + floss_yr008 + 
          floss_yr009 + floss_yr010, family=binomial, data=comm.vars6)
```

I tried to apply the *exact* argument to variable number 26th ("titled") when running the *Match* function. The code looks as following:

```
rr1 <- Match(Y=Y, Tr=Tr, X=glm1$fitted, exact = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), M=1, replace = T)
```

Nevertheless I got the following warning message:

```
Warning message:
In Match(Y = Y, Tr = Tr, X = glm1$fitted, exact = c(0, 0, 0, 0,  :
length of exact != ncol(X). Ignoring exact option
```

I believe this is a problem related to the structure of X (=glm1$fitted). Because when I just use the following matrix:

```
 Z<-with(comm.vars6,data.frame(AREA_HA , SUMVIV_TOT , SUMPOB , COUNT , luz , potable , cocina_ele , altitudeme , river_mean , 
                 paved_mean , unpaved_me , VDep_mean , VNacional_ , VVecinal_m , temp_mean , rain_mean , dccpp_mean , 
                 distfloss_ , idh_mean , bmass_mean , slope_mean , distANP_me , ker10_mean , titled , for10 , floss_yr001
                 , floss_yr002 , floss_yr003 , floss_yr004 , floss_yr005 , floss_yr006 , floss_yr007 , floss_yr008 , 
                 floss_yr009 , floss_yr010 , for10_per))
```

as X and rerun the Match function:

```
rr1 <- Match(Y=Y, Tr=Tr, X=Z, exact = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), M=1, replace = T)
```

It works fine!

How should the code look like in order to be able to use both the Propensity Score (glm1$fitted) and the exact argument = 1 for "titled"?

Comment: Welcome to SO!, this warning ,`length of exact != ncol(X). Ignoring exact option`, indicates that `length` of input vector to `exact` does not match `length` of `glm$fitted`. Could you update the post with N (number of  explanatory variables), M (length of input vector to `exact`. And if feasible output of `dput(head(comm.vars6,5))`

Comment: As Osssan says, this is your problem, glm$fitted produces a vector, so feeding the exact argument any vector larger than 1, does not make sense when the only matching covariate you are using is the PS. If you want to perform an exact match on some variables and also include the PS, construct a data.frame to feed the X argument that also includes the exact match vars.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough sketch of what the function should look like using two variables: PS (distance match) and titled (exact match):

```
# get X mat
myMatchMat <- data.frame("PS"=glm1$fitted, "trim"=comm.vars6$trim)
# match
rr1 <- Match(Y=Y, Tr=Tr, X=X, exact = c(0, 1), M=1, replace = T))
```

Because you haven't provided a dataset, I can't test the code, so there may be a couple changes you have to make, but this is how the `Match` function works.